# What to do when we see cross-posts from Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, faq

Periodically I see an exact duplicate that has been posted on *Stack Overflow*, and then here.

Should these be flagged as exact duplicates?

Comment: I have created a [filter](http://stackexchange.com/filters/22660/drupal-questions) to find duplicate questions asked on both the sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flag the question that has been asked on *Stack Overflow*, and report the link to the exact duplicate asked on *Drupal Answers*.

[image: screenshot]